# Optimize method in python. Similar to permutation

Tags: python, optimization, permutation

I have a method which generates me number of passengers to reservation process. The parameters are the minimum and maximum numbers of passengers.

There are only 2 conditions:

- `number_of_adults` must be greater than 0
- `number_of_infants` must be less than or equal to `number_of_adults`

This is code:

```
    def generate_numbers_of_paxes(min_number=1,max_number=9):

    number_of_passengers=random.randint(min_number, max_number)
    print(number_of_passengers)
    number_of_adults=random.randint(min_number, number_of_passengers)
    number_of_youths=random.randint(0, number_of_passengers-number_of_adults)
    number_of_children=random.randint(0, number_of_passengers-number_of_adults-number_of_youths)
    number_of_infants=random.randint(0, number_of_passengers-number_of_adults-number_of_youths-number_of_children)
    number_of_adults+=number_of_passengers-number_of_adults-number_of_youths-number_of_children-number_of_infants
    if(number_of_adults<number_of_infants):
        difference=number_of_infants-number_of_adults
        number_of_infants-=difference
        number_of_adults+=difference

    return [number_of_adults,number_of_youths,number_of_children,number_of_infants]

numbers_of_paxes=generate_numbers_of_paxes()
for (x,y) in enumerate(numbers_of_paxes):
    print(x,y)
```

This code works good, but as you can see there is some problem in line

```
number_of_adults+=number_of_passengers-number_of_adults-number_of_youths-number_of_children-number_of_infants
```

because sum of number for every age group isn't always  equals `number_of_passegers`, and I add difference to `number_of_adult`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what this has to do with permutation…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `number_of_infants` calculation should be simply:

```
number_of_infants = number_of_passengers - number_of_adults - number_of_youths - number_of_children
```

Otherwise it is likely to be lower than the required number to meet your passenger requirements (a `random` number between `0` and `number_of_passengers - number_of_adults - number_of_youths - number_of_children`).

However... you are better calculating the number of infants *before* adults and then calculating the number of adults with `number_of_infants` as the minimum for the `random()`, given the constraints you listed. Leave the number of children until last and apply the same logic. Since this looks like homework, I'll not provide the code for this.

That is to say:

1. Generate random number of passengers
2. Generate random number of infants
   (can't be more than half of number
   of passengers)
3. Generate random number of adults
   (must be at least number of infants)
4. Generate random number of youths
   (can't be more than passengers less
   infants less adults)
5. Number of children is number of
   passengers less previous three
   groups.

Also, why are you doing this?

```
for (x,y) in enumerate(numbers_of_paxes):
    print(y)
```

Either do:

```
for (x,y) in enumerate(numbers_of_paxes):
    print(x, y)
```

Or:

```
for y in numbers_of_paxes:
    print(y)
```

Comment: @user278618: You've not followed all of my advice. You should only need to assign to each of those variables once. Ordering is important. Also, please don't edit the original code. It makes the thread hard to read for those coming along later.

Comment: Ok, I'll never edit original code, thx. Just umber_of_infants = number_of_passengers - number_of_adults - number_of_youths - number_of_children is not enough, because number of infants can't be more than number_of_adults, and it's possible to random 5 of all passengers, then random 1 adult, 1 youth, 1 and children, and then I can get 2 as number for infants. This is way I later use variable difference

Comment: If you choose `number_of_passengers` first, then whatever you choose _last_ *cannot* be random: it must be `number_of_passengers` less all the other `number`s. Like I say in my answer, you should calculate the `number_of_infants` **before** `number_of_adults`.